# Display first row of joined table along with parent table using laravel-9

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Product table and ProductImage Table. Product has unique rows, and ProductImage table have rows based on Product table id, name is product_id(may be multiple).

**Product table is**

```
id | product_name

1  | product1
2  | product2
```

**ProductImage table is**

```
id | product_id | product_image

1  |    1       |  image1
2  |    1       |  image2
3  |    1       |  image3
4  |    2       |  image4
5  |    2       |  image5
```

Now I need join with row from Product table and only last rows of ProductImages based on product_id.

**Result should be:**

```
id | product_name | product_id | product_image

1  | product1     |   1        |   image3
2  | product2     |   2        |   image5
```

Please use the table names i give to avoid confusion. Thankyou so much!
I want it on laravel 9 eloquent or query builder it's up to your suggestion.

Comment: are you going to use this result one time ?

Comment: Do you have product and product image model?

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Comment: yes i use product model and product image model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not posted your MySQL version so I provide two solutions:

```
-- mysql 8 solution
with t as (
    select 
        product_name,
        product_id,
        product_image,
        row_number() over (partition by product_id order by pi.id desc) rn
    from products p
    left join product_image pi on p.id = pi.product_id
) select product_id, product_name, product_image from t where rn = 1;

-- mysql 5 solution
select 
    p.product_name,
    pi.product_id,
    pi.product_image
from products p
join product_image pi on p.id = pi.product_id
join (
  select max(id) last_id, product_id from product_image group by product_id
) li on last_id = pi.id;
```

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/62ef0c91536938c1d89570fb463bbc4b/)

Then you want to use Laravel:

```
<?php
$query = 'with t as (
    select 
        product_name,
        product_id,
        product_image,
        row_number() over (partition by product_id order by pi.id desc) rn
    from products p
    left join product_image pi on p.id = pi.product_id
) select product_id, product_name, product_image from t where rn = 1;';

// Select using Laravel
$data = $db::select($db::raw($query));

print_r($data);
```

[PHP online editor](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0bc389d9fc21f8f2110b5d102ebc5479/php/php81/3c7e560c56af1c62c5e3e19614edeae0/)